# on mouse over show associated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div class "asset-container" with a data-id attribute.
I also have a div class "popover-content" with an associated data-id.

When I hover over "asset-container", I want the "popover-content" show.

There are a lot of these, which is why I have data-id attached to each of the two divs so I can call the associated div to show.

I have tried several iterations of script and am not getting anywhere

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    custom_popover();
});
function custom_popover() {
    $(".asset-container").mouseover(function() {
    $('.popover-content [data-id=' + this.value + ']').show();

   });
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="col-xs-4">
    <li class="thumnail-video">
        <div class="popover-content" data-id="71"></div>
        <div class="asset-container">

    <video class="img-responsive portrait" type="video/mp4" src="https://ternpro-development.s3.amazonaws.com/media/films/71/mobile/3.mp4" data-id="71">      </video>

    </div>
</li>

</ul>
<ul class="col-xs-4">

<li class="thumnail-video">
    <div class="popover-content" data-id="69"></div>
    <div class="asset-container">

    <video class="img-responsive landscape" type="video/mp4" src="https://ternpro-development.s3.amazonaws.com/media/films/69/mobile/2.mp4" data-id="69"></video>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that `.asset-container` does not have an attribute `value`. You could try replacing `this.value` with `$(this).children("video").data("id")`.

Comment: yes I noticed that and so I added the data-id attribute value to the asset-container but still no luck

Comment: Oh wait it did work!

Comment: now the only thing is, is that sometimes, there are assets with the same data-id, but in different containers that should not show, this might be another question

Comment: I don't see an element with class `popover` anywhere. Is the element on the same `.asset-container`?

Comment: please see my edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$(".asset-container").mouseover(function() {
   var id = $(this).children("video").data("id");
   $(this).parent().children('.popover-content[data-id=' + id + ']').show();
});
```